# How to insert a field in an existing document in MongoSH

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mongo-shell, mongodb-update

I've to insert a new field with a boolean value in some documents in the `students` collection with the following structure:

```
{
  _id: ObjectId("61c9cffcf9b7043141272c5b"),
  createdAt: 2021-12-27T14:38:52.025Z,
  updatedAt: 2022-07-26T10:12:56.887Z,
  deletedAt: null,
  fullName: 'Karina Kuznetsova',
  address: 'Chicago IL',
  Major:'Computer Science',
  __v: 0,
}
```

I'm running the following query in MongoSH locally in Mongo Compass:

```
db.students.aggregate([
    {
        $match: { 
            "_id": ObjectId('61c9cffcf9b7043141272c5b')
        }
    },
    {
        $set: { "transferred": true }
    }   
]);
```

I'm expecting the field to be added to the document like this:

```
{
  _id: ObjectId("61c9cffcf9b7043141272c5b"),
  createdAt: 2021-12-27T14:38:52.025Z,
  updatedAt: 2022-07-26T10:12:56.887Z,
  deletedAt: null,
  fullName: 'Karina Kuznetsova',
  address: 'Chicago IL',
  Major:'Computer Science',
  __v: 0,
  transferred: true
}
```

However, the original document remains the same, without the `transferred` field.

**Option 2**

I've also tried this way:

```
const studentsList = db.students.find({
    "_id": ObjectId('61c9cffcf9b7043141272c5b')
});

studentsList.forEach(student => {
    const result = db.students.updateOne(
        { _id: student._id },
        {
            $set: { "transferred": true }
        });
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Option 2 I suspect is due to the provided `student._id` being a string type, the unmatched data type, it can't find any document to update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `update` function instead to update the document.

The `aggregate` function is used to return the queried document, but will not update the existing document in the collection.

```
db.students.update(
    {
        _id: ObjectId('61c9cffcf9b7043141272c5b')
    },
    {
        $set: { "transferred":true }
    });
```

Comment: Makes sense. How can I change the matching part if I've to provide a list of multiple ids? Can I use it so: {   
            "_id": {
                     "$in": [
                        ObjectId('61bc782d34bede442f74f1a4'),
                        ObjectId('63640225bbd4264c580dec83'),
                        ObjectId('6203aa908b92b246f2f1be86'),
                        ObjectId('63292a40f3ec13470d00ed22')
                     ]
                }
        }

Comment: Yes, you can provide the `$in` operator. [Demo](https://mongoplayground.net/p/_YqoHs7Uedo)

Comment: Works! I had to add `{ multi: true }`.

Comment: Ya, forgot to mention that you need `{ multi: true }` for updating multiple documents. =)